# How to restrict the visibility of the users as host?

Tags: android, zoom-sdk

I am starting to build a Web and Android application that requires the Zoom meeting functionality.

But my app has a special requirement for Zoom meeting: ***The host can see all the participants in the meeting whereas the participants can only see the host in the meeting***.

I am looking at those API for [Web](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/web/build/meetings/join) and [Android](https://marketplace.zoom.us/docs/sdk/native-sdks/android/overview), but I cannot find any feature that can restrict the visibility to achieve the functionality I want to implement.

Is it possible to implement that in Zoom?

Answer (score 1):

So I have been working on exactly the same thing.

On your Android app, you can have a completely customized view for the meeting and add the video stream of your host only. Once you join the meeting you can get the host by using the following code:

```
public long getHost() {
    long userId = host;
    if (userId == -1) {
        List<Long> users = inMeetingServiceObject.getInMeetingUserList();
        for (long user : users) {
            if (inMeetingServiceObject.isHostUser(user)) {
                userId = user;
                host = user;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return userId;
}
```

and then add the video:

```
private MobileRTCVideoViewManager mDefaultVideoViewMgr;
mDefaultVideoViewMgr.addAttendeeVideoUnit(getHost(), renderInfo);
```

But as far as the Web is concerned, they are rendering the video in a canvas and there is no way that I could find to manipulate the stream till now. The rest of the elements like hiding the buttons and stuff can be easily handled through CSS.

Just to mention: I started integrating Zoom with React just a few hours back.